# Drawing something after putImageData "erases" the content of a canvas (Chrome bug?)

Tags: google-chrome, dom, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm developing a type of image viewer, and want to do the following:

1. Create an image using `new ImageData()`, and draw it on a canvas using `ctx.putImageData()`.
2. Draw some additional UI (e.g., grid, ruler) on top of it using the traditional canvas API such as `ctx.lineTo()`.

My code had worked fine until around Chrome 103, but suddenly `ctx.lineTo()` and so on started to "erase" some parts of what's already drawn on the canvas. The same code still works fine on Firefox. The following is a minimum reproduction code.

```js
const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// Create an ImageData with random pixel data
// (Actual pixel data come from a rare image format)
const image = new ImageData(canvas.width, canvas.height);
for (let i = 0; i < image.data.length; i += 4) {
  image.data[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
  image.data[i + 1] = 0;
  image.data[i + 2] = 0;
  image.data[i + 3] = 255;
}

const drawFrame = async () => {
  ctx.putImageData(image, 0, 0);
  await delay(200);
  ctx.strokeStyle = "blue";
  ctx.lineWidth = 5;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(Math.random()* 128, Math.random() * 128);
  ctx.lineTo(Math.random()* 128, Math.random() * 128);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.stroke();
  await delay(200);
  requestAnimationFrame(drawFrame);
};
drawFrame();
```

```html
<html>
  <body style="background: #ddffff">
    <canvas width="128" height="128" id="canvas"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Left**: Expected (Firefox); **Right**: Broken (Chrome)

[image: Firefox] [image: Broken (Chrome)]

At first, I thought this could be a bug related to GPU synchronization or something, but waiting a few hundred milliseconds after `ctx.putImageData()` does not solve the problem. The problem does not happen if I use `ctx.drawImage()` instead, but I need to have access to individual pixel data.

So what am I missing? Do I need to call something that tells the browser to "flush" the internal buffer? Or is this a known Chrome bug?

Comment: https://crbug.com/1361165

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks, visiting `chrome://flags` and disabling "Accelerated 2D canvas" fixed this issue temporarily, so I agree that this is the same bug. I can wait for Chrome 107.